# Checkbox not getting right order

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have these checkboxes used for identifying (if checked) should email the respective client, it's supposed to be pre-checked.

But when it is pre-checked, and then when I unchecked one checkbox e.g multipayment_email[1], when submitted to PHP the one getting unset is the last index multipayment_email[4].

`list_payments.php`:

```
<form method="POST">
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery) { ?> 
    <input type="text" name="multipayment_name[]" required/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="multipayment_email[]" checked />
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

SUBMIT_payment.php:

```
$names = $_POST['multipayment_name'];
$emails = $_POST['multipayment_email'];

foreach ($names as $key => $name)
{
     $email = isset($emails[$key]) ? 1:0;

     $query = "INSERT INTO payments() VALUES (NULL, '$name', $email)";

     $response['message'] .= $query."<br/>";
}

die(json_encode($response));
```

So when I submit the form this is the output (given that I unchecked the 2nd index out of 5 check boxes):

```
"INSERT INTO payments() VALUES (NULL, '1 waw', 1)"

"INSERT INTO payments() VALUES (NULL, '2 wew', 1)"

"INSERT INTO payments() VALUES (NULL, '3 wiw', 1)"

"INSERT INTO payments() VALUES (NULL, '4 wow', 1)"

"INSERT INTO payments() VALUES (NULL, '5 wuw', 0)"
```

It should be

"INSERT INTO payments() VALUES (NULL, '2 wew', 0)"

any enlightenment?

Comment: It's not really related to your question but this code is vulnerable to sql injection. Imagine what would happen if someones *name* was `', ''); DROP TABLE payments;`

Comment: Your `$name` and `$emails`array size does not the same so you can't use `$names` keys to `$emails`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="POST">
<?php $idx = 0; ?>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery)): ?>
    <input type="text" name="rows[<?php echo $i; ?>][name]" required/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rows[<?php echo $i; ?>][email]" checked />
    <?php ++$idx; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</form>
```

And so if third checkbox is unchecked, you will obtain the $_POST data in this format:

```
array(
    'rows' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'the value of name 1',
            'email' => 'on'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'the value of name 2',
            'email' => 'on'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'the value of name 3'
        )
    )
)
```

Checkboxes that doesn't check will have the field unset and not being posted, and from there you can easily do an `isset` check to know if it's checked or not.

```
$rows = $_POST['rows'];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $email = isset($row['email') ? 1 : 0;
    $name = $row['name'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO payments() VALUES (NULL, '$name', $email)";
    $response['message'] .= $query."<br/>";
}
```

**But DO WARNED that this code is susceptible to sql injection. Since this is out of the scope of this question let us not dive into that here :)**

Comment: thanks sir, I've made different approach instead, thanks to the concept you've given me.

instead I've made a dummy input type with value of = 1 (which changes if unchecking the corresponding checkbox).

so I wont have to deal with the unset checkbox index.

Tho this is really good sir, I'm just more comfortable with lesser loops on PHP files. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

All Inputs need to have different names.
Now there are a faw Inputs with two names `multipayment_name[]` and `multipayment_email[]`

Answer (score -1):

The last one is not being unchecked, this line of code is giving you the undesired result.

```
$email = isset($emails[$key]) ? 1:0;
```

When you uncheck the checkbox, it won't be submitted to the server. dump your submitted checkboxes array i think you will get it )

Comment: I've tried this sir, but the problem is that the index count will be a bit off, therefore not really suitable in my case.  thanks tho :D